# Spring unit test with H2 database with MySQL mode: How to fix COLLATE and CHARACTER SET

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, unit-testing, h2

I am running unit tests with `H2 database` and I am using `MySql` for running in prod.
I have a create query with `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATE`, and h2 is not supporting this, due to this the tests are failing.

I have tried with adding `MODE=MYSQL` in the url. But that is not working for `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATE`.

Is there a solution in which I don't have to create a separate sql file for h2.

Comment: I recommend you test with the same product and version that you will use in production — MySQL. The unit tests are inconclusive if you test with a different DBMS. All SQL implementations are slightly different, and what works on one may not work on another. Even if the tests passed on your local H2 instance, you don't want to be surprised by a bug in production, when you could have been aware of the bug during testing.